# Download Manager for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

What is a good Download Manager for Mac?
Are there free ones available?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several choices :

- [Folx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyiIK.png) :

> Folx is a free download manager for Mac OS X with a true Mac-style
>   interface. It offers convenient downloads managing, flexible settings,
>   etc. Folx has a unique system of sorting and keeping the downloaded
>   content.

[image: Folx Screenshot]

- [iGetter](http://www.igetter.net/downloads.html):

> iGetter is a full featured download manager and accelerator. With
>   iGetter you can get the most out of your Internet connection be it
>   dial-up, wireless, cable, DSL, T1 and other high end broadband
>   connections. iGetter can greatly improve the speed of your downloads
>   using segmented (accelerated) downloading.

[image: iGetter Screemshot]

- [Leech](http://manytricks.com/leech/) (paid one) : clean UI.

> Every modern browser has its own download functionality, so why should
>   you use a separate application for handling downloads in the first
>   place? Because Leech works better than any built-in download manager.

[image: Leech]

- [jDownloader 2](http://jdownloader.org/download/index)

> JDownloader is a free, open-source download management tool with a
>   huge community of developers that makes downloading as easy and fast
>   as it should be. Users can start, stop or pause downloads, set
>   bandwith limitations, auto-extract archives and much more. It's an
>   easy-to-extend framework that can save hours of your valuable time
>   every day!

[image: jDownloader]
 - [Fat Pipe](http://fatpipeapp.com/): (free)

> Most servers and internet service providers limit the speed a single
>   connection can have. We can bypass these limits by splitting a
>   download task up into many smaller chunks. This guarantees that you
>   will fully saturate your internet connection.

http://fatpipeapp.com/media/demo.mp4

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommended you use [iGetter](http://www.igetter.net/iGetter.html) it was better than other one.

- [iGetter](http://www.igetter.net/iGetter.html)

but also can use

- [Download Accelerator Plus (DAP)](http://www.speedbit.com/mac/)
- [Folx (free)](http://mac.eltima.com/download-manager.html) but can pay money and upgrade it to pro

Also if you can use terminal and install package I recommended you use [AXEL](http://wilmer.gaast.net/downloads/axel-1.0b.tar.gz) I myself use this one. after install it you can use this like below in terminal

```
axel -n 100 -s 5242880 "your download link"
```

the -n 100 show the number of your connection to the server

and the -s 5242880 use for limiting the speed,-s 5242880 in above example will try to keep the average speed around 5242880 (5120 Kilobyte per/sec).

Answer (score 3):

[Aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) bundled with [WebUI](https://github.com/ziahamza/webui-aria2/) is the best you can get on OS X. All you have to do is run Aria from Terminal and open WebUI in Browser.

Features

- **Multi-Connection Download.** aria2 can download a file from multiple sources/protocols and tries to utilize your maximum download bandwidth. Really speeds up your download experience.
- **Lightweight.** aria2 doesn’t require much memory and CPU time. When disk cache is off, the physical memory usage is typically 4MiB (normal HTTP/FTP downloads) to 9MiB (BitTorrent downloads). CPU usage in BitTorrent with download speed of 2.8MiB/sec is around 6%.
- **Fully Featured BitTorrent Client.** All features you want in BitTorrent client are available: DHT, PEX, Encryption, Magnet URI, Web-Seeding, Selective Downloads, Local Peer Discovery and UDP tracker.
- **Metalink Enabled.** aria2 supports The Metalink Download Description Format (aka Metalink v4), Metalink version 3 and Metalink/HTTP. Metalink offers the file verification, HTTP/FTP/BitTorrent integration and the various configurations for language, location, OS, etc.
- **Remote Control**. aria2 supports RPC interface to control the aria2 process. The supported interfaces are JSON-RPC (over HTTP and WebSocket) and XML-RPC.

Answer (score 2):

I use [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) a lot. It is extremely useful if you're downloading content from the cloud (to name the popular one: Rapidshare, Hotfile, Megaupload).

And it's free.

Answer (score 2):

Let's not forget [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) for Firefox. Yes, it's a plug-in for Firefox, but since Firefox also runs on the Mac, this makes it a valid answer. It's free too.

Answer (score 2):

**[Fat Pipe](http://fatpipeapp.com)** - (free) has plugins for Chrome, Safari, and Firefox
[image: Fat Pipe App]

*note: I am extremely biased (i wrote fat pipe);*

I used to use Speed Download but they recently stopped supporting their app and i was getting a bunch of errors.

Fat Pipe actually supports up to 50 connections per download and automatically determines connection count based on file size.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for disclosing your affiliation. Be sure to participate with questions that are not directly related to your product for the best reception from the community.

Answer (score 1):

As much as this saddens me but I would also recommend [jDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/). On the other hand for some simple and not so simple cases you could opt for wget or curl. You could be evan braver and create a batch script using one of those UNIX commands and be done with it.

Comment: This should probably be a comment since your answer is the same as nanda. Also, I think you mean `bash` not `batch` script.

Comment: You are absolutely right, just an old habit from MS DOS times:)

Answer (score -4):

I think download managers are uneeded, at least, anymore. This question was asked 4 years ago, I know, but Download Managers are useless in today's world.

Need a download manager still? Your browser. Done!

Comment: Download managers are not limited in simple browser download functionality. Scheduling, download bandwidth adjustments, resume capabilities, BitTorrent features, remote control, and many other hacks are features that will not included in browsers.