# How can I remove duplicated items in the install updates list?

Tags: macos, software-update

I just tried to install the OS X 10.10.3 update from the App Store. My internet is slow and after several hours, it finally finished.  It asked to restart, and I accepted.  But nothing happened.  I clicked the "Update" button again, and told it to restart several times, to no avail.

After a few tries, it started the **whole download again!!!!**

I cancelled it (I'll have to try again tomorrow), but now my Installed Updates list shows this:
[image: Repeated updates listed]
And I don't know how to remove all the duplicate entries... or just a good installation of the update!! This is my first Mac, and is a serious negative experience for me... Other OS beta releases aren't this bad!! Any idea on how I can fix it?

**EDIT:** I was able to install the update with the combo updater, but the repeated updates are still appearing.  Does anyone have any idea what file I can edit to get it listed only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something, somewhere, didn't register correctly.

Possibly someone maybe able to figure out exactly which receipt or App Store file to find, however, it would be far simpler & possibly safer to just get the standalone [OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 Combo Updater](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) & run it again; because you don't know what else didn't happen as planned either & the Combo will make sure everything since 10.10.0 is correctly updated.

You can use a download manager to fetch it, too & it will then be resumable if the download halts for any reason.
- examples at [Download Manager for Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1109/download-manager-for-mac-os-x) [though Speed Download, arguably the best, is discontinued.]

Comment: I'm downloading the Combo Updater. Thanks for your answer!! We'll see how it goes :)

Comment: Wish you luck :)

Comment: The combo updater installed the update correctly, and the duplicate updates eventually went away as newer updates pushed them down.